# WCF Exception: Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I'm trying to host a WCF web service on a separate Website in IIS with https at 443 as the only binding.

The following configurations works well when I use it in a website which uses both the bindings (http(80) / https(443)). If I remove the http binding, it starts throwing the following error.

***Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https].***

**How do I make it work in an IIS website with https binding only?**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="defaultBasicHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/ERPService/retailPayment.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="defaultBasicHttpBinding"
                contract="RetailPaymentService.RetailPayment.SVRetailPaymentService" name="EnterpriseRetailPayment" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyEndPointBehavior">
          <!--<SchemaValidator enabled="true"/>-->
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="SettlementSalesCollection.SaleItemService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
        <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="MyEndPointBehavior" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  name="SettlementSalesCollection"
                  contract="SettlementSalesCollection.CITransactionSettlementListenerService" />
        <endpoint name="mexEndpoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="SchemaValidator"
             type="SettlementSalesCollection.SchemaValidation.SchemaValidationBehavior+CustomBehaviorSection, SettlementSalesCollectionService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: change your client endpoint to https? eg `endpoint address="https://localhost/ERPService/retailPayment.svc`

Comment: That is another service used by this service. It runs at http. I just posted the full <system.serviceModel> config section

Comment: Maybe add `<add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />` to the `<protocolMapping>` section?  That's the default for WCF (so it should be there unless you're inheriting from another config file), but it might be worth trying.

Comment: I'm still having the same problem. Is there a way to work with both HTTP and HTTPS without changing the Web.config? Some customers have both bindings in IIS, and others have only HTTPS...

I don't want to edit the Web.config because it will be overwritten on updates...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your configuration should look similar to that. You may have to change `<transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />` depending on your needs for authentication. The config below doesn't require any authentication.

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBindingConfiguration">
            <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
            </security>
        </binding>       
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
    <service name="XXX">
        <endpoint
            name="AAA"
            address=""
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingConfiguration"
            contract="YourContract" />
    </service>
<services>
```

That will allow a WCF service with `basicHttpBinding` to use HTTPS.

Answer (score 18):

In my case this fixed the issue

1. Go to Project Properties by clicking F4 on the project name
2. Set SSLEnabled = true

[Project Properties Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcJhw.png)

Answer (score 13):

You can get this if you ONLY configure `https` as a site binding inside IIS.

You need to add `http(80)` as well as `https(443)` - at least I did :-)

Comment: (right click on website and select `Edit Bindings`)

Comment: Just realized my answer isn't really an answer because the questioner specifically wanted to avoid doing this - but I'll leave it up as it seems to be helping some people who must have found this question via the error message.

Comment: this is what worked for me

Answer (score 12):

My issue was caused by missing bindings in IIS, in the left tree view "Connections", under Sites, Right click on your site > edit bindings > add > https

Choose 'IIS Express Development Certificate' and set port to 443
Then I added another binding to the webconfig:

`<endpoint address="wsHttps" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DefaultWsHttpBinding" name="Your.bindingname" contract="Your.contract"  />`

Also added to serviceBehaviours: 
`<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />`

And eventually it worked, none of the solutions I checked on stackoverflow for this error was applicable to my specific scenario, so including here in case it helps others

Comment: This is the problem I was having.  My config has both bindings for HTTP and HTTPS.  I found that the Default IIS Website does not include bindings for HTTPS.  You need to add that, if your config has endpoints for both HTTP and HTTPS.

Answer (score 4):

I tried the binding according to the answer by @Szymon but It did not work for me. I tried **basicHttpsBinding** which is new in .net 4.5 and It solved the issue. Here is the complete configuration that works for me.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpsBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpsBindingForYourService">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpsBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="YourServiceName">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpsBinding" bindingName="basicHttpsBindingForYourService" contract="YourContract" />
      </service>
    </services>   
</system.serviceModel>
```

FYI: My application's target framework is 4.5.1. IIS web site that I created to deploy this wcf service only has https binding enabled.

Comment: This worked for me. Important to also ensure that the targetFramework in httpRuntime is set accordingly i.e. <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />

Answer (score 3):

My issue was also caused by missing https binding in IIS: 
Selected default website > On the far right pane selected Bindings > add > https

Choose 'IIS Express Development Certificate' and set port to 443

Answer (score 1):

In my case the binding name in under protocol mapping did not match the binding name on the endpoint. They match in the example below.

```
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpsBinding" contract="serviceName" />
```

and

```
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Open IIS And right click on Default App Pool and Add Binding to make application work with HTTPS protocol.

type : https

IP address : All unassigned

port no : 443

SSL Certificate : WMSVC

then

Click on and restart IIS

Done

Answer (score 0):

I received same error
Fix it by:

customBinding --> binding --> httpTransport   *Change to*   http**s**Transport

binding="mexHttpBinding"  *Change to*  binding="mexHttp**s**Binding"

For binding="wsHttpBinding" *Add* bindingConfiguration="_WsHttpBinding"
Under system.serviceModel --> bindings add the following section:

```
 <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="_WsHttpBinding">
        <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
        </security>            
      </binding>
 </wsHttpBinding>
```