# Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, iis-7

I am getting this message when I attempt to access my service:

```
Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https]. 

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https].

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 

[InvalidOperationException: Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https].]
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.MakeAbsoluteUri(Uri relativeOrAbsoluteUri, Binding binding, UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses) +17430541
   System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadServiceDescription(ServiceHostBase host, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceElement, Action`1 addBaseAddress, Boolean skipHost) +1097
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.LoadConfigurationSectionInternal(ConfigLoader configLoader, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceSection) +89
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.ApplyConfiguration() +162
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses) +207
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) +475
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) +43
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +578
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +1451
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +76
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +901

[ServiceActivationException: The service '/fileservice/fileservice.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https]..]
   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +654324
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +210877
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +282
```

I am using a config almost identical to another service I wrote on the same url different folder and I'm having no issues.

This is my web.config:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0" debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <caching>
      <outputCacheSettings>
        <outputCacheProfiles>
          <add name="DefaultCache" duration="60" varyByParam="none" />
        </outputCacheProfiles>
      </outputCacheSettings>
    </caching>
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpEndpointBinding">
          <security mode="None">
            <!-- Basic <security mode="Transport"> -->
            <!-- To use Basic auth, just comment Windows and use this, but you need to configure basic in IIS as well -->
            <!-- <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" /> -->
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="default">
          <security mode="None">
            <!-- Basic <security mode="Transport"> -->
            <!-- To use Basic auth, just comment Windows and use this -->
            <!-- <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" /> -->
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="FileStorageService.FileService">
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndpointBinding" contract="FileStorageService.IFileService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="default" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior" contract="FileStorageService.IFileService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

The only thing I changed was the namespace and service name. The namespace for this service is `FileStorageService` with the service name being `FileService`.

I have really nothing in the server, as you can see in the code:

```
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace FileStorageService
{
  // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IFileService" in both code and config file together.
  [ServiceContract]
  public interface IFileService
  {
    [OperationContract]
    void DoWork();
  }
}

namespace FileStorageService
{
  // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "FileService" in code, svc and config file together.
  public class FileService : IFileService
  {
    public void DoWork()
    {
    }
  }
}
```

It's the basic information when a new service is created. It is publishing to a SSL domain, so it requires https.

All I'm attempting to do is get it published so I know it is working so I can move on.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: did you tried Jon Barker solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the rep to post as a comment, so here's a comment as an answer...

I believe the problem is that you're attempting to host an SSL based service, but your binding configuration doesn't have a transport security type. You need to modify the security mode on your basic binding to support transport security. See here for the answer:

[WCF Exception: Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918213/wcf-exception-could-not-find-a-base-address-that-matches-scheme-http-for-the-en)

If that doesn't help, try hosting the service as a non HTTPS based service initially, so see if that works. This will validate the rest of your configuration is correct.

Comment: Here's a better link:

http://blog.adnanmasood.com/2008/07/16/https-with-basichttpbinding-note-to-self/